# Autolayout not working with Custom Keyboard, is this an Apple bug, or am I missing some settings?

Tags: ios, autolayout

In a regular app, in the initial viewController, if I add two UIHorizontalStackViews, and add two buttons to each, and set their heights to be 0.5 of the view, while setting the left, top, and right properties to 0, they behave as we expect:

[image]

However, if I do this exact same process on a custom keyboard extension that uses a viewController, I get this:

[image]

You would think that it would make each UIHorizontalStackViews take 50% of the keyboard height, but no the keyboard shrinks and the buttons get smaller.

I then tried adding one single vertical stackview, that had 4 rows of horizontalstackviews, making it have height of 1.0 of it's view, and margins of left 0, top 0, right 0, in this case, the window ended up taking far more than half of the screen, more than the custom keyboard's height is allowed to be.

Not sure if this is a bug or what. I was assuming autolayout would be adjusting the keyboard height depending on screen orientation, and phone model.

Comment: The buttons have an intrinsic content size that they will attempt to be sized at if there isn't something telling them to be a different size.  The keyboard view wants to be as compact as it can be while respecting the constraints of its subviews.  This results in the buttons getting the height of their intrinsic content size and the keyboard being just tall enough to fit the two buttons that each take up half of its height.

Comment: So what is the solution to having 1 vertical stack view, containing 4 horizontal stack view filled with keys? This would allow for simple spacing between all keys, and allow them to be displayed the same across phone models, and in both portrai and landscape

Comment: Can you add some pictures of what you're getting with the vertical stack view and how you want it to look?

Comment: Pretend I want it to look exactly like the iOS main keyboard. I have it working by forcing a height of 56 on each horizontalStackView, but it's not ideal as it doesn't work when I rotate the phone, and is slightly off across different devices.

Comment: Any way I try to set it up with autolayout, it doesn't seem to respond correctly. I doubt I would need to identify the screen size or device and then force the view to be a certain height